# Jquery email validation

Tags: php, jquery

After getting help from @juhana (thank you again) I ended up with theese codes to validate email input:

validate email:

```
function validateEmail(){
var a = $("#email").val();
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "check_email.php",
  data: "email="+a,
  success: function(rsp){
   //if it's valid email
   if(rsp == "ok"){
    email.removeClass("error");
    emailInfo.text("");
    emailInfo.removeClass("error");
    return true;
}

else
//if it exists
if(rsp == "exists" ){
 email.addClass("error");
 emailInfo.text("E-mail already in use");
 emailInfo.addClass("error");
 return false;
}

else
//if it's NOT valid
if(rsp == "invalid"){
 email.addClass("error");
 emailInfo.text("Please type a valid E-mail");
 emailInfo.addClass("error");
 return false;
 }
}
});
}
```

check_email.php

```
<?php
require_once('db_conn.php');
require_once('is_email.php');

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
if (is_email($_POST['email'])){
echo 'ok';

$checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT E_mail FROM orders WHERE E_mail='$email'");
$email_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkemail);

if($email_exist>0){
echo 'exists';
}
}else{
echo 'invalid';
}
?>
```

Now 2 out of 3 are working the "ok" and the "invalid" ones... the "exists" doesn't.

What's wrong here???

Thank you

Comment: What goes wrong where exactly, can you clarify? What does `is_email()` dio, where it is defined?

Comment: is_email is my email validation file... My ajax success is working if msg is **"ok"** or **invalid**. If msg is **"exists"** is not working. Basically is not looking if email exists.

Comment: Your last five questions had indistinguishable titles. Please be more descriptive and less vague. *This* question seems about SQL woes rather. Did you test if it works if you invoke the `check_email` script manually with known parameters?

Comment: Sorry about the titles... Didn't pay much attention... I will be more carefull next time.

Comment: btw, for debugging use something like firebug -- if you'd looked at the output from your PHP that the browser received, the error would have been obvious. :)

Comment: I am using it but I didn't see any error... (of course I just started to use it few days ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by reading your code above, if the email was valid, but existed in the database, it would return "okexists" which would cause your javascript to fail. You'd need to change it to something like this:

```
<?php

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT E_mail FROM orders WHERE E_mail='$email'");
$email_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkemail);

    if (is_email($_POST['email'])){
        if($email_exist) {
            echo "exists";
        }
        else {
            echo "ok";
        }
    } else {
        echo "invalid";
    }

?>
```

This allows it to return *only* the token "exists" when its a valid, but existing email. And *only* the token "ok" when its a valid, not previously existing email. And of course it returns invalid if it doesn't pass the `is_email()` test.

Comment: Ahhh.... I changed it to that a minute before you post... :) BUT my real mistake was that I was looking for e-mail in the WRONG table... Sorryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy!

Comment: So there were two errors -- no way anyone here could have known the problem was in the database. Its often best to reduce problems to the smallest possible, self-contained example that reproduces the issue. Even if that means writing something new to exhibit the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
var email= $("#emailid").val();
if(!filter.test(email)){
        alert('Plz enter valid email id');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code and how it solves the issue.